# 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED' : after upgrading to latest next JS version

Tags: reactjs, next.js, package, dependencies, upgrade

Did upgrade the nextjs version 12 to @latest, post that facing the error, while running dev server:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './cjs/react.development' is not defined by "exports" in /home/oem/Desktop/cld-frontend/cld-frontend/node_modules/react/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:453:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:729:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.mod._resolveFilename (/home/oem/Desktop/cld-frontend/cld-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:23:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED',
  page: '/colleges/[collegeUriSlug]'
}
```

old dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "cld-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "mongodb": "^4.10.0",
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "npm": "^8.12.2",
    "react": "17.0.2", 
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^2.7.1", 
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-select": "^5.4.0",
    "sharp": "^0.30.5"  
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint": "8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0"
  }
}
```

new dependencies after upgrading:

```
{
  "name": "cld-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "mongodb": "^4.10.0",
    "next": "^13.0.5",
    "npm": "^8.12.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^2.7.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-select": "^5.4.0",
    "sharp": "^0.30.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint": "8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.5"
  }
}
```

did try some of the methods, available on internet:

1. yarn upgrade
2. deleting node_modules and package.lock.json and reinstalling dependencies
3. npm update and npm audit fix --force

all these methods didn't worked for me,s till facing the issue, unable to access the website.

Comment: Upgrade react to 18

Comment: go back to your previous working version and have a look at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide

Comment: Did try the guidelines, provided on above link, but still facing the issue.